# How to sync MySQL database between two servers

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to sync a MySQL database between two servers.

If a new record will be added in server A, then server B fetch new record.

If a new record will be added in server B, then server A fetch new record.

Comment: There is answer here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350799/how-to-synchronize-mysql-databases-between-local-and-hosted-servers-automaticall/18351058#18351058

Answer (score 4):

You should probably go for Master-Master Replication .

http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication

Comment: Master to Master Replication has data loss?

Comment: Well mate its open source, and it can't actually work the way we pray. But if you know what your application does, and with  test cases that you try to break the replication, I'm sure you will find a way to fix it. And that's how it works if you want to keep it flawless. May I help you if I know on what case does data loss occur for master/master according to you?